# ¿Hay algún programa que resuelva las dependencias en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Me ocurre que el 90% de los scripts de python que me bajo tienen las librerias desactualizadas y no me funcionan, y tengo que buscar a pelo la nueva versión de la libreria e instalarla con.

```
pip install modulo
```

Y aún así suelen surgir errores de incompatibilidad entre versiones y me veo obligado a editar el código (algunas veces con suerte y otras no).

Me pregunto si existe algún programa que resuelva las dependencias en python. Es decir, que lea el escript, resuelva las dependencias invocando a 'pip' y que además modifique el código para que por ejemplo actualice las diferencias entre python 2 y python 3.

Decir que he intentado usar un programa que se llama **Py2to3** pero este tambien está desfasado y no funciona (y aunque funcionará tampoco haría todo lo que yo digo).

Que desastre de lenguage, por un lado es estupendo porque con 3 líneas haces lo que con C++ harías con tres páginas, y además tiene un montón de librerias muy útiles que dificilmente encuentras para C++. Pero por otro lado le hacen tantos cambios al lenguaje y a las librerias que no sabes si un programa que escribes hoy dentro de un mes te va a funcionar.

Pues eso, si exitiera tal herramienta sería un punto a favor para este lenguaje. ¿Alguien sabe si existe?

Comment: Creo que confundes compatibilidad con obsolescencia. Python2 ya tiene más de 15 años y se mantiene actualizado gracias a que se hacen algunos *backports*. Si quieres usar librerías antiguas, usa la versión de python2 que sea necesaria.

Comment: Yo prefiero usar lo mas nuevo.. El problema es que cuando te bajas un código no te suelen decir de que versión de python es... y lo que me gustaría es que existiera un programa que te ponga el código al dia.. tanto en librerias como en sintaxis. Eso sería estupendo

Comment: Lo reciente en python3 es usar tipado gradual, programación asíncrona y *dataclasses*; módulos como `pathlib` o `requests` han dejado obsoleto el modo habitual de hacer algunas tareas básicas. Poco de esto se aprovecharía migrando código antigua. De python2 te puedes traer la experiencia adquirida, pero mejor que no te traigas el código.

Comment: SI, estoy de acuerdo contigo si se mira desde ese punto de vista. Pero el poblema que yo le veo es que en la práctica no es tan fácil. Es decir, si me bajo un script es porque quiero usarlo lo antes posible y sin tener que editarlo y actualizarlo para que funcione. Es decir a mi me interesa lo que hace y no como lo hace... Y también pienso en las horas que se invirtió en hacer ese escript para que al final no sirva para nada porque quedó obsoleto.

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista, un script que no está bien documentado, sin especificar la versión de python ni las librerías que necesita, y sin saber cómo funciona, sólo sirve para perder el tiempo, ya que ni sabes si lo que hace lo hace bien, ni sabrás de dónde vienen los fallos. Si pretendes crear software de calidad, usa código que esté actualizado y mantenido.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, pero casi nadie hace eso. Incluso he bajado scripts de Google para usar el API de YouTube y ni siquiera ellos dan esa información completamente detallada. Si que tienen una buena documentación para usar el API pero por ejemplo por ningún lado verás que versión de python usaron para elaborar el script. Y si, hasta estos scripts he tenido que editarlos un poco para hacerlos funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` resuelve las dependencias hasta cierto punto. Cuando instalas un paquete con `pip` él instalará también aquellos de los que dependa, salvo si ya estaban instalados, que es cuando pueden aparecer problemas de incompatibilidades si la versión que tenías ya instalada no coincide con la que necesitaría el paquete que estás instalando ahora.

Para evitar este tipo de problemas (o minimizar su impacto) lo típico es usar *entornos virtuales* que son carpetas dentro de las cuales se instalan todos los paquetes necesarios para una cierta aplicación, de modo que no interfieran con otros instalados globalmente o con otros entornos virtuales de otras aplicaciones.

`virtualenv` es una utilidad para crear estos entornos virtuales, que había que instalar aparte. Desde Python 3, viene incluída con el propio Python de modo que en lugar de `virtualenv` puedas usar `python -m venv` para lograr el mismo objetivo.

Más recientemente está tomando mucho auge la herramienta [`pipenv`](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) que junta el control de dependencias de `pip` con los entornos virtuales y promete resolver todos los problemas de dependencias. Dicen que en el futuro cercano podría formar parte de Python y ser el mecanismo de instalación de paquetes recomendado.

Entretanto puedes leer una buena explicación [aqui](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/)

Comment: Muchas Gracias @abulafia